# How to remove a polyline from an RGB image using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am not sure what would be the best way to remove a vertical polyline from an image. This line starts from the very top of an image to the bottom. The input is an `image with three channels` and `array of y indices of the line`. The output would be the same input image but without the polyline. For example, if the first image shape is `(5, 10,3)`, then the final image shape should be `(5, 9, 3)` after removing the polyline.

#### Input example:

**Image**:

```
np.array([[[0, 20, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 20, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 56, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 58, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0]],
          [[0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 30, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 31, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 32, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 31, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0]],
          [[1, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [1, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

Note: the size here is (3, 5, 10) for illustration. The image shape would be (5, 10, 3). We wanna remove the white polyline

**Polyline**:

```
np.array([4, 4, 5, 5, 6])
```

#### Output Example

```
np.array([[[0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 56, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 58, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
          [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 31, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 31, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
          [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

Note: the size now is (3, 5, 9)

**My code**

```py
def remove_polyline(image, polyline):
    h, w = image.shape[:2]
    res_image = np.zeros((h, w - 1))

    for i in range(h):
        left_section = image[i, :polyline[i]]
        right_section = image[i, polyline[i]+1:]
        res_image[i, :] = np.dstack((left_section, right_section))

    return res_image
```

I know this would work for grayscale images but not sure about 3 channel images

Comment: Just draw over it with background color. See cv2.polylines() at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga1ea127ffbbb7e0bfc4fd6fd2eb64263c

Comment: This is different, I need to shrink the image by removing the polyline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your input has shape `(3,5,10)` instead of `(5,10,3)`. This answer assumes the latter:

```
def remove_polyline(s, polyline):
    mask = np.arange(s.shape[1]) != polyline[ :, None]
    return s[mask,:].reshape(s[:,:-1].shape).copy()

r = remove_polyline(image, polyline)
plt.imshow(r)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
def remove_polyline(image, polyline):
    h, w, c = image.shape
    res_image = np.zeros((h, w - 1, c))

    for i in range(h):
        left_section = image[i, :polyline[i], :]
        right_section = image[i, polyline[i]+1:, :]
        res_image[i, :, :] = np.vstack((left_section, right_section))

    return res_image
```

Comment: I think you just need to add the type in `res_image` so it would be: `res_image = np.zeros((h, w - 1, c), dtype=int)`

Comment: Ok that makes sense.